# How to check if a floating point exception happened using Go?

Tags: go, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

I'm trying to create a program that receives an expression with floating point numbers and shows if any exceptions occurred.

I know that if I wrote it in C, it would be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>

//floating point math happens before calling the function
void displayExceptions() {
    printf("Exception FE_DIVBYZERO: %d\n", fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO));
    printf("Exception FE_INEXACT: %d\n", fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT));
    printf("Exception FE_INVALID: %d\n", fetestexcept(FE_INVALID));
    printf("Exception FE_OVERFLOW: %d\n", fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW));
    printf("Exception FE_UNDERFLOW: %d\n", fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW));
}
```

Is there a way to check those exceptions in go?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no; however many of them will produce `NaN`, `Inf` or `0.0`, which can be tested for using `math.IsNaN(x)`, `math.IsInf(x)` and `x == 0.0`.